# In a REST API, should you correct user input on server side?

Tags: rest, api, api-design, user-interface

We have a REST API with an endpoint accepting JSON data from the client. One of the JSON fields is a URL that will be rendrered to other users as a hyperlink to a website page associated to the resource. Somewhere in the pipeline we needed to ensure the URL is valid (starts with `http(s)://`, contains a domain from a whitelist, etc.).

So we designed the API such that it would accept only valid URLS, and return an error (400) when the URL is considered invalid. On the UI side, the user has to correct the URL until it is valid, the error message adapting to the error case (missing value, invalid domain, invalid format...).

Our product owner tested our implementation before going live, and had trouble with this simple approach. He typed in "facebook.com/foobar" and was expecting the URL to be valid. The error message was something along the lines of "Please enter a valid URL like https://www.example.com/xxxx". He was expecting (quite rightly) that the input field would accept anything a browser address bar would accept. The error message could have been clearer ("the URL should start with http(s)://"), but we agreed he was right and that in this case, user input should be fixed by our application before being saved.

Here we had 2 ideas:

- Either let the API correct the URL (prepend a default protocol) upon saving ;
- Or prepend the protocol on the client side, and don't touch the API validation.

I have a strong preference for the client-side method, because I believe a REST API should never alter user input silently (you never know what kind of client will consume your API, and silently modifying user input could have unexpected side-effects). The problem is I couldn't find any real-life example to back up my point of view.

On the contrary, one of my teammates (the one responsible for the fix) couldn't find any good reason to prefer one method over the other, and went for the API fix (mainly because it's much faster to implement, and you don't have to implement this behavior for each client using your API).

What do you think?

Comment: As a general rule, I'd avoid 'correcting' invalid inputs where possible. It's not always obvious what a sensible default should be (did your teammate go with `http://` or `https://`?), it makes your API more complex for consumers and can lead to unpredictable or unintuitive behaviour, and the code that tries to fix bad data is likely to be a source of perplexing bugs.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with not silently modifying the user input, it could cause for confusion and doesn't perfectly reflect the JSON data the end-user submitted.

Although client-side user input verification can be circumvented, it's still a wise move to show the user that his url is going to be modified before it will be consumed.

In any case, always verify the input server-side, because you could assume the data (in this case the url) is well-formed, but the user has complete control over the UI and could submit faulty data resulting in a nasty server error.

Answer (score 4):

For me there is a clear winner.

You should always ask yourself who is responsible for what?. For me, the Rest API (and any API) should be kept simple, never add behaviors outside what's expected from it, in this scenario, the API has the role of storing data for latter use, **so no, do not fix it silently**.

Also, if you add this responsibility to the API, where do you draw the line of what should be fixed and what not?

If you need consistency on the client side, add a class in your consumer API that manages this kind of issues and reuse it everywhere you consume the API.

Comment: I agree. The question specifically mentions that the concerns about the URL validation are focused around the UI, so the validation should be done there, since the users seem concerned about reporting the error and offering a chance to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

There's one option which hasn't been mentioned, and that is change the definition of what constitutes correct input to the API. Make "facebook.com" an acceptable field value (note: the field is now **NOT** a URL), and document that. Then no *correction* is necessary. The API then uses this field to construct a hyperlink when generating a subsequent response, if necessary, just like it would use a date of birth to compute an user's age.

The rest of my point of view follows what [Dan Wilson](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/378583/28660) wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue in this specific case since the URL reference is well-known. Your service should have no problem accepting `facebook.com/foobar` or `https://www.facebook.com/foobar` as valid input.

You know the URL references a Facebook page, Facebook pages can always use HTTPS, and Facebook will perform redirection if `www` is not specified.

I would not modify the user input; I would simply

- validate that it matches the format of a URL

  - add a missing scheme only in your test for validation so that truly invalid data (`facebook=com\foobar`) can be rejected
- store whatever the user gave you as-is
- format it appropriately (add missing `https://`) when rendering it

Should the user need to modify the URL in the future, they can be presented with exactly what they entered and will not be surprised by any modifications.

You can account for user expectations while not modifying the data.

Comment: I wouldn't add the `https://` prefix before `mysite.org/xxx`, even if the domain is facebook, because that's not the behavior a browser has by default. When you type `mysite.com` in your address bar and hit enter, the browser performs a GET request on `http://mysite.com`, and only thereafter mysite.com OR your browser's redirect cache OR your browser's [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) list changes that to `https://mysite.com`. I think you should stick to the `http://` prefix, otherwise you might encounter odd behaviors the user may not understand.

Comment: This answer and @MaximeRossini 's very valid response are a brilliant illustration of why trying to fix bad input is nearly always a bad idea

Comment: @MaximeRossini But using plain HTTP is not correct either. There's a reason why browsers use HSTS and if you interpret a schema-less string as an URL, you should probably implement HSTS, too.

Comment: @maaartinus The implementation of HSTS is the reponsability of the client opening the URL, isn't it? If the API was to open a connection to the URL sent by the user, that would be something to consider. But in any case I think it shouldn't affect the value persisted by the API.

Comment: @MaximeRossini Maybe. We know nothing about the use of the URL. It may be opened by the server in this or a different API call or maybe in a background job. It may be opened by the client which may or may not profit from HSTS of a browser and the client may or may not be the responsibility of the OP or their team. In case, there's a HTTPS access to a given site, I'd prefer to store the HTTPS address, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be any real reason to prefer one over the other.

Essentially you have a method you want to expose (it would be nice to have some real names here)

```
service.Method(urlLikeString)
```

and some code which changes a url like string into a url. There are three possible places to put it

1 the application

```
app.Method(urlLikestring)
{
    url = getUrl(urlLikestring)
    client.Method(url);
}
```

2 the client

```
app.Method(urlLikestring)
{
    client.Method(urlLikestring);
}

client.Method(urlLikestring)
{
    url = getUrl(urlLikestring)
    httpclient.post(url)
}
```

3 the server

```
client.Method(urlLikestring)
{
    httpclient.post(urlLikestring)
}


server.Method(urlLikestring)
{
    url = getUrl(urlLikestring);
    logic.Method(url);
}
```

Unless there is a scenario where you *don't* want the UrlLikeString converted, or the conversion requires information that only one of the layers has. It doesn't make any difference where you put the conversion.

Obviously you still have to verify the urlLikeString is url-like whatever you do